# How to increase highlighted color of a particular date in FSCalendar(Swift 5.0)

Tags: swift

I am trying to increase the size of highlighted colour of a particular date in FSCalendar.The below is the code am using also am attaching.Please let me know what i am missing.Thank you

```
func setUpCalendar() {
        calendar = FSCalendar(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 150, width: self.view.frame.size.width - 30, height: 150))
        calendar.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        calendar.scope = .week
        calendar.allowsMultipleSelection = false
        calendar.appearance.separators = .interRows
        calendar.rowHeight = 30.0
        calendar.appearance.headerTitleColor = UIColor(hex: "FF7271")
        calendar.appearance.todayColor = UIColor(hex: "FF7271")
        calendar.appearance.selectionColor = UIColor(hex: "FFEFEF")
        calendar.appearance.titleSelectionColor = .black
        calendar.appearance.weekdayTextColor = .systemGray
        calendar.appearance.headerMinimumDissolvedAlpha = 0
        calendar.appearance.headerTitleFont = UIFont(name: "System", size: 0)
}
```

Comment: are you trying to disable header?

Comment: yes am trying to disable header.

Answer (score 0):

hide like this. go to `storyboard` / `xib` what you used.

```
goto design -> go to Atrributed inspector and set header height = 0
```

[image]

as per you define it programatically than just write this line

```
calendar.headerHeight = 0
```